# Suppress logging from Java VM being used in Python with jpype

Tags: logging, jvm, jpype

Have some Python code that is interacting with a JVM via the `jpype` package.  The code in the JVM has some overly verbose logging that is getting dumped to the console and I would like to suppress it, preferably by setting the logging display level to some desired value Like WARNING or Error.

Looks like the Java code is just `java.util.logging`

Comment: You haven't provided enough information about the JVM application, what logging framework it uses, etc. This is not really a Python logging issue, more a JVM/JVM app one,

Answer (score 0):

Was able to just do (in the Python code):

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("Logger Name").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF)
```

But only because I was able to find the name of the logger in the Java code